# How do I scrape citation count from Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar

I have a list of publications in a CSV file for which I need to scrape the citation count of these papers from Google Scholar. I have a code to try do this, but naturally, it does not let me scrape after going through a couple of papers. I would like some advice on how to do this. It would be useful to hear solutions to either run some code multiple times *or* get an API to do it. I only have some 400 papers, so would like to possibly avoid paying for that, but I would like to explore different solutions here (and also how to go about it, as I am a beginner at scraping/using APIs/etc).

This is my code:

Import libraries

```
import os
import json
import pandas
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

For Setting File Path

```
path = r'(this is the path name in my computer)'
```

Read CSV File and Get citation count

```
df = pandas.read_csv('Publications_Local.csv')
article_titles = df.title

def get_citations(title):
    url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=' + title.replace(' ', '+')
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
    element = soup.find('a', text=re.compile(r'\bCited by\b'))
    if element:
        citations_text = element.text
        citations_number = re.search(r'\d+', citations_text).group()
    else:
        citations_number = None
            
    return citations_number

for title in article_titles:
    citations = get_citations(title)
    if citations is not None:
        print(f'Article: {title}')
        print(f'Number of Citations: {citations}')
        print('---')
    else:
        print(f'Article: {title}')
        print('No citations found for article')
        print('---')
```

Comment: This sounds more like a question for https://stackoverflow.com/. That said, the [scholarly](https://github.com/scholarly-python-package/scholarly) package should serve you well.